# C++ how to get handle to exception thrown in generic catch handler

Tags: c++

Is there any way to get handle to exception thrown inside generic catch block.

```
try
{
    throw ;
}
catch(...)
{
// how to get handle to exception thrown
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`std::current_exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception).

Rearranging from cppreference:

```
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
     eptr;
    try {
        std::string().at(1); // this generates an std::out_of_range
    } catch(...) {
        std::exception_ptr eptr = std::current_exception(); // capture
    }
}
```

Inside the `catch(...)` block, the current exception has been captured by the `exception_ptr eptr`. The exception object referenced by an `std::exception_ptr` remains valid as long as there remains at least one `std::exception_ptr` that is referencing it: `std::exception_ptr` is a shared-ownership smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that is C++, an exception is allowed to be of any type and not only a subclass of `std::exception`. That's the reason why the common idiom is to use only exception classes derived from `std::exception` to have a coherent interface.

You can always as suggested by @PaoloM use `std::current_exception()`. But it has some limitations that make it hard to use, because to be allowed to represent any type of exception it is a `std::exception_ptr` that only can (ref. in [cpluscplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception_ptr/)):

- be default-constructed (acquiring a null-pointer value).
- be copied, including being copied a null-pointer value (or nullptr).
- be compared against another exception_ptr object (or nullptr) using either operator== or operator!=, where two null-pointers are always considered equivalent, and two non-null pointers are considered equivalent only if they refer to the same exception object.
- be contextually convertible to bool, as false if having null-pointer value, and as true otherwise.
- be swapped, and being destructed.

> Performing any other operation on the object (such as dereferencing it), if at all supported by the library implementation, causes undefined behavior.

If you want to be able to to serious things with an exception, you should use dedicated exception handlers:

```
try
{
    throw ;
}
catch (MyException& a) {
// Ok, it is a know type and I know how to deal with it
}
catch (std::exception& e) {
// it is a subclass of std::exception, I can at least use its what() method
catch(...)
{
// I can get a std::exception_ptr from current_exception, but cannot know what to do with it
}
```